# Does signing into Chrome merge Google Accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, merge, google-accounts

I've been using my computer at work for about three months so far and it's accumulated its fair share of bookmarks and history entries. I wanted to be able to access both the bookmarks and history from different computers and to have a back-up copy.

After searching for a few minutes, I found out I could do that by signing into Chrome. When I tried to do that, I got the the message you can see in the attached [image: screenshot]

Chrome does have bookmarks and history entries from before I started using it. However, they are mostly work-related, so I would not mind having them become part of my account. I am worried about causing problems for the person who was using the computer before me.

I've tried creating a new user, but it turns out that way I will not have access to any history entries that were created before the new user account.

My question is: if I press the "Sign in Anyway"-button, will I be causing problems to the person who was using Chrome before me?